# Show only one result from MySQL in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I got a problem, I built a inbox page, And I want to do that when a user clicks on the sender name the message slides down, but when someone clicks on the sender name all the messages slides down, because the message SQL is in a loop and its under the same class name..

```
      $(".message").hide();
  $(".sender").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.message').toggle("fast");
  });

    <table width="850px" style="background: #424242; border-radius: 10px;">
<?php
$messagesql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toid='$myid' ORDER BY id LIMIT 10";
$messageres = mysql_query($messagesql);


while ($messagerow = mysql_fetch_array($messageres))
{
  $fromid = $messagerow['fromid'];
  $fromsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$fromid'");
  $fromrow = mysql_fetch_array($fromsql);
  if($messagerow['viewed'] == 0)
  {
    echo '<tr style="width: 800px; background: #30cafd;"><td style="border-radius: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">';
    echo '<font size="5"><b><span class="sender">'.$fromrow['username'].'</span></b></font><br>';
    echo '<span class="message">'.$messagerow['message'].'</span>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
  }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Quick fix: change `limit 10` to `limit 1`

Comment: You should use different id's for the different message container elements to be able to distinguish them. (Append a rowid or a counter for example.)

Comment: its not next() closest('tr').next() is returning next tr thats why its opening all next messages. use like this `$(this).parents('td').find('.message').toggle('fast');`